# How can I make an option in a SELECT multi line upon clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down with items in it that overflow horizontally but I want to make an option multi-line when I click it so that I can see it all.

I can try a tool tip but I know the tool tip doesn't last long.

How can I implement this multiline idea or something similar that would work without having to introduce jquery ui and all that?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this should do it

```
$('#identifier').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr('multiple','multiple');
});
```

Comment: Note, 'multi-line', not multiple selection. This isn't what the OP is looking for.